# Resize text to fit a label in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, xcode6, autolayout

I want to display some text in a label.

The label has a fixed size but the text can vary from one single word to a complete sentence.

Is there a way to automatically resize the text in such a way that it is alway displayed in the largest possible font-size without truncating it?

I'm working through tutorials for days now, but can only find ways to adjust the label size, not the text size.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set `minimumScaleFactor` property of `UILabel`.

[image: How to set minimumScaleFactor]

Comment: Don't forget `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`

Answer (score 34):

You can change the font size to fit the width of the UILabel (non-multiline):

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: Super!Do you know if there is a way to do this also with multiple lines??

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite sure, you might want to look into textViews but I'm not sure